# I have an error with instantiate in a CompressedTexture 2d

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

I tried to make an animation of an animated sprite appear when defeating an enemy, however it does not allow instantiate to be used because the function does not exist in compressedTexture2d

```
const EnemyDeathEffect = preload("res://Action RPG Resources/Effects/EnemyDeathEffect.png")
```

```
func _on_stats_no_health():
    queue_free()
    var enemyDeathEffect = EnemyDeathEffect.instantiate()
    get_parent().add_child(enemyDeathEffect)
    enemyDeathEffect.global_position = global_position
```

I tried changing the instantiate to a get_image but it didn't work and I followed forums but it doesn't work and I don't know what to do

Answer (score 0):

When you `load` or `preload` (or [similar](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/io/background_loading.html)) you get a `Resource`.

There are many kinds of `Resource`s in Godot, and you can define custom ones too.

One particular case of a `Resource` is a `PackedScene`, which is a serialize structure of `Node` (what we would call a "scene"). Usually `PackedScene` is saved to storage as a `.tscn` (text scene) or `.scn` (*binary* scene) file. And `PackedScene` has an `instantiate` method which will give you a `Node` back (actually gives you a bunch of `Node`s, but you get the reference of the root of the scene).

And just to be completely clear, no, `Node`s are not `Resource`s. In fact, `Resource`s do not exist in the scene tree. You add `Node`s to the scene tree (e.g. with `add_child`) and `Node`s could reference `Resource`s (the other way around is strongly discouraged, I'll skip on the reasoning for the purposes of this answer).

Here, of course, you are not dealing with a scene, but a texture, a `CompressedTexture2D`, which is also a kind of `Resource`, and - as you discovered - it does not have an `instantiate` method.

*For people arriving to Godot from Unity: Godot does not have an scene/prefab distinction. If you want to instantiate things inside of your scene, those are also scenes. This means that: 1. You never have to convert between scene and prefab. 2. An scene could be used either way, or neither, or both (yes, there are use cases). 3. It is up to you to keep it organized.*

*Now that you know... The question is what exactly do you want do to.*

---

**Instantiate an scene**

Perhaps you meant to create an scene, in which case you can do that, save it to a file and use it. And the result would be some `Node` that you can add to the scene tree (with `add_child`) as you do.

```
var enemyDeathEffect = EnemyDeathEffect.instantiate()
get_parent().add_child(enemyDeathEffect)
```

Since you say you want "an animated sprite", I'm going to recommend you actually create an scene with an `AnimatedSprite2D` so you can configure it using the Godot editor instead of dealing with it from code.

See [2D sprite animation](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/2d/2d_sprite_animation.html).

*For people arriving to Godot from Unity: I'll reiterate that Godot does not have an scene/prefab distinction. So get used to the idea that you make an scene for things you reuse inside other scenes.*

---

**Create a `Node` and give it the texture**

Perhaps you actually mean to use the `CompressedTexture2D`. But since the `CompressedTexture2D` is not a `Node` it cannot be added to the scene tree, thus you would need to create a `Node` that uses it.

No, Godot will not create a `Node` automatically for you. Godot cannot guess which kind `Node` you want... You have a few options, for example `Sprite3D`, `Sprite2D`, `TextureRect` and so on. In fact, you could have created a custom `Node` type and want to use that.

For a simple case, this is how you would create an `Sprite2D`:

```
var sprite := Sprite2D.new()
sprite.texture = EnemyDeathEffect
get_parent().add_child(sprite)
```

Since you say you want "an animated sprite"... To create the `AnimatedSprite2D` we need to create an `SpriteFrames` (this is another `Resource`) and to create that we are going to need to slice the texture to get the individual sprites.

Here I'm assuming there are 10 frames, each of 100 by 100 pixels, in a single row, and I create an animation "my_animation" from them:

```
var animated_sprite := AnimatedSprite2D.new()
var frames := SpriteFrames.new()

var source_data := EnemyDeathEffect.get_image()
for index in 10:
    var frame_data := Image.create(100, 100, false, Image.FORMAT_RGBA8)
    frame_data.blit_rect(
        source_data,
        Rect2i(
            index * 100,
            0,
            100,
            100
        ),
        Vector2i.ZERO
    )
    var frame := ImageTexture.create_from_image(frame_data)
    frames.add_frame("my_animation", frame)

animated_sprite.sprite_frames = frames
get_parent().add_child(animated_sprite)
```

This also illustrates what `get_image` does: It gives you an `Image` object which you could use to draw and to create textures from.

Answer (score 0):

En realidad es que no habia adjuntado el animated sprite en el odigo, si no solo el png, asi que gracias sin ti no me hubiera dado cuenta :P